# Centering text in the middle of the page one on top of the other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some issues trying to create a main page of a website responsive. I am in the beginning and I have no clue how to do it. Basically I am trying to have some text on top of the other but have it readable. I also try to make it mobile responsive and what I have right now it just doesn't look right.

```
<p>Hello, there!</p>
```

## Interactive Design Student.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Get In Touch</a></li>
</ul>
```

and my css

```
h1 {
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    font-size: 51px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    margin: 15px;
}

p {
    left: 0;
    line-height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #232324;
    font-size: 160px;
    margin:15px;
}
```

[image: this is how it looks like]

Comment: It's better if you create a codepen so people can try and see how it works and try to help you with it...

Comment: Semi-accurate demo for those interested: https://jsfiddle.net/nxgL09z1/

Comment: Can you create a picture in Photoshop and show what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with `Flexbox` and `:after` **pseudo element**, here is a full [`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/525/)

```css
body {
  background: #282828;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.homepage {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
h1:after {
  content: "Hello There";
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.2;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
  <h1>Another interactive design student.</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I am a beginner so I didn't know about the :after pseudo element.